# reassemble equivalent in Getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

what is the reassemble(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/reassemble.html) equivalent in Getx? How can I track hot reload?

thanks:)

this is the part of code what i would like to done with Get:

```
 @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      controller.pauseCamera();
    }
    controller.resumeCamera();
  }
```

Comment: Wow, same question's answer I am searching now. :D

Answer (score 0):

in `Getx`, to achieve the same goal as using the `reassemble` method, you can use:

```
    Get.forceAppUpdate();
```

Calling this function will reconstruct the application from the sketch, use this with caution. Your entire application will be rebuilt, and touch events will not work until the end of rendering.